# ASP WebApi : Service layer, business layer and data access layer

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, service, webapi

If I need to write a simple webapi which need to get/create/update/delete of the products. Is this really need a business layer.

I am using Entity Framework which I understand this is similar to Repository Pattern.

If my webapi application is very simple which not much complex business logic e.g. bank reconciliation etc

Do i really need to have a business logic layer? Can i just have a service layer which create products / remove the products etc..

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary at all to have a business layer! (*with a disclaimer*)
Let me support my argument and address your concern

- One of the most basic design principles of software engineering is [KISS](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/keep-it-simple-stupid#:%7E:text=Keep%20it%20simple%2C%20stupid%20(KISS)%20is%20a%20design%20principle,of%20user%20acceptance%20and%20interaction.). If you feel the business problem you are solving is pretty simple then why to make code complex by introducing unnecessary layers.
- Not having the 'business layer' is not a crime. It is well supported by the community as well that's why in one of the community and industry loved framework [Spring](https://spring.io/) there is a module called [spring-data-rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) exactly supporting design you are proposing (simple code with business layer and on top without explicit web layer)
- The last argument **evolutionary approach**. With the increasing complexity of system and technology community released that system and code complexity should be evolved (thought process every well explained [here](https://evolutionaryarchitecture.com/)). Don't try to think about future today (again referring to another basic design principle [YAGNI](https://medium.com/better-programming/yagni-you-aint-gonna-need-it-f9a178cd8e1)). (*Explaining disclaimer here*) So start from simple and if in future you felt the need of having separate business logic layer because you got to write some actual business solving code then introduce that layer and evolve it!